# Read byteswritable file from hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My mapreduce job is currently writing the output(byte array) as byteswritable in a file. Now I need to read this bytearray in my java program. When I am accessing the output file in my java program its taking the bytewritable as string.

How can I read the byte array directly from the output file in my java program? Or if I can write to the output file as byte array instead of bytewritable in my mapreduce job.

Comment: You need to provide the code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

For write job:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat.class);
```

For read job:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.class);
```